# What is 1st party aPI?

Tags: api

So, this is pure curiosity. I've heard the term 3rd party API, as in, "3rd party API" for quite a while.  I wonder why we say 3rd and not 2nd (or 4th)?  Who are the first and second parties API and where did the term come from?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/251644/who-are-the-1st-and-2nd-parties

Comment: An API that you own, host, and can change vs an API that a 3rd party (not you) owns, hosts, and can change.